# CodeIgniter Pagination configuration is wrong?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Please take a look at the following code in a controller named "test":

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

// These 3 are the minimum config that needs to be set
$config['base_url']   = base_url() . 'test/?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', '&amp;');
$config['total_rows'] = 173;
$config['per_page']   = 20;

// This returns something like this: ?name=foo/20
// I would expect something like this: ?name=foo&per_page=20
// $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

// This retuns something like this: ?name=foo&per_page=20 (which is what I want),
// but the documentation says it should be: ?c=test&m=index&per_page=20
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Then go to: `test/?name=foo`

The resulting pagination links look correct. When you click on, say, link number "2", you are redirected to `?name=foo&per_page=20` which is correct. However, the new pagination created looks wrong. It looks something like this: `?name=foo&per_page=20&per_page=40` (where per_page appears twice in the query string).

What's going on?

Comment: Why can't U try `.htaccess` for easy way of organizing `params` in `URL` ?

Comment: The query `per_page` is added by CodeIgniter and because you use `http_build_query` in the base_url, CodeIgniter is going to append per_page every time (even if it already exists in the URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add uri segments

```
$config['uri_segment'] = x ;
```

Comment: Sorry. Can you explain further? This is to define which URI segment contains the page number. I'm not using URI segments; I'm using query string for my pagination.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: If U use `.htaccces` assign `$config['uri_segment']` with 3...